# How to use addView in loop to make a rows in table layout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I want to make a table that have to call my data from my database using JSON and volley, so i need to loop it. In my loop i have a few textview and i use `addView` to add it to the row.The `addView` was works well if i only have one row data in my database but it will get an error if i have more then one. The error is

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first`.

So, i think its get an error because the loop was call a same `addView`.

Sorry, I'm not too fluent in English :)

Here is my code:

```
public class DaftarNilaiUtama3 extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_daftar_nilai_utama3);

        final  TableLayout tableview = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableview);

        final TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

        final TextView tvModul = new TextView(this);
        final TextView tvRes = new TextView(this);
        final TextView tvPost = new TextView(this);


        TableLayout.LayoutParams lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(5,5,0,5);


        row.setLayoutParams(lp);

        Response.Listener responseListener= new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    List<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
                    JSONArray jsonMainNode = new JSONArray(response);
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {

                        jsonResponse = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                        String nama_modul = jsonResponse.optString("nama_modul");
                        String responsi_nilai = jsonResponse.optString("responsi_nilai");
                        String posttest_nilai = jsonResponse.optString("posttest_nilai");


                        tvModul.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        tvModul.setTextSize(12.0f);
                        tvModul.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));
                        tvModul.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        tvModul.setText(nama_modul);
                        row.addView(tvModul);


                        tvRes.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        tvRes.setTextSize(12.0f);
                        tvRes.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));
                        tvRes.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        tvRes.setText(responsi_nilai);
                        row.addView(tvRes);

                        tvPost.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        tvPost.setTextSize(12.0f);
                        tvPost.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));
                        tvPost.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        tvPost.setText(posttest_nilai);
                        row.addView(tvPost);


                        tableview.addView(row);
                    }




                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        RequestTableDNU3 lvReq = new RequestTableDNU3(nama_klp,nama_mhs, responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(DaftarNilaiUtama3.this);
        queue.add(lvReq);




    }



}
```

Comment: Just check whether defining the three textViews inside the loop persists the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..You have to create table row for each iteration in loop and then have to add to table layout. add context as DaftarNilaiUtama3.this

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                    final TableRow row = new TableRow(DaftarNilaiUtama3 .this);
                    jsonResponse = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                    String nama_modul = jsonResponse.optString("nama_modul");
                    String responsi_nilai = jsonResponse.optString("responsi_nilai");
                    String posttest_nilai = jsonResponse.optString("posttest_nilai");


                    tvModul.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    tvModul.setTextSize(12.0f);
                    tvModul.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));
                    tvModul.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    tvModul.setText(nama_modul);
                    row.addView(tvModul);


                    tvRes.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    tvRes.setTextSize(12.0f);
                    tvRes.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));
                    tvRes.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    tvRes.setText(responsi_nilai);
                    row.addView(tvRes);

                    tvPost.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    tvPost.setTextSize(12.0f);
                    tvPost.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));
                    tvPost.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    tvPost.setText(posttest_nilai);
                    row.addView(tvPost);


                    tableview.addView(row);
                }
```

Comment: if put a `final TableRow row = new TableRow(this);` in the loop, it have an error in `this` code. Its say `TextView in TextView cannot be applied to Response.Listener`

Comment: if i put a final `TableRow row = new TableRow(this);` in the loop, it have an error in word `this`. The error is `TableRow (android.content.Context) in TableRow cannot be applied to (anonymous com.android.volley.Response.Listener.<java.lang.String>)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create from the row layout object (new TableRow and new TextView) for each row you want to add. This should work:

```
public class DaftarNilaiUtama3 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_daftar_nilai_utama3);

        final TableLayout tableview = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableview);

        Response.Listener responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    List<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
                    JSONArray jsonMainNode = new JSONArray(response);
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {

                        jsonResponse = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                        final TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

                        final TextView tvModul = new TextView(this);
                        final TextView tvRes = new TextView(this);
                        final TextView tvPost = new TextView(this);

                        TableLayout.LayoutParams lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        lp.setMargins(5, 5, 0, 5);

                        row.setLayoutParams(lp);

                        String nama_modul = jsonResponse.optString("nama_modul");
                        String responsi_nilai = jsonResponse.optString("responsi_nilai");
                        String posttest_nilai = jsonResponse.optString("posttest_nilai");


                        tvModul.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        tvModul.setTextSize(12.0f);
                        tvModul.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));
                        tvModul.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        tvModul.setText(nama_modul);
                        row.addView(tvModul);


                        tvRes.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        tvRes.setTextSize(12.0f);
                        tvRes.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));
                        tvRes.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        tvRes.setText(responsi_nilai);
                        row.addView(tvRes);

                        tvPost.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        tvPost.setTextSize(12.0f);
                        tvPost.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));
                        tvPost.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        tvPost.setText(posttest_nilai);
                        row.addView(tvPost);


                        tableview.addView(row);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        RequestTableDNU3 lvReq = new RequestTableDNU3(nama_klp, nama_mhs, responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(DaftarNilaiUtama3.this);
        queue.add(lvReq);
    }
}
```

Comment: if i put a final `TableRow row = new TableRow(this);` in the loop, it have an error in word `this`. The error is `TableRow (android.content.Context) in TableRow cannot be applied to (anonymous com.android.volley.Response.Listener.<java.lang.String>)`